# Is my laptop likely to work with a 12 cell battery?

Tags: laptop, battery

I am looking for a new battery for a Gateway MT6839B laptop. The current battery is a 6 cell 6MSBG. A number of replacement battery vendors, including [this one](http://www.batterie-king.fr/batteries.php/GATEWAY/SQU-412/1.html), seem to imply that a 12 cell will work as well. On the whole is this the case? Is a 12 cell battery compatible with a machine that was delivered with a 6 cell battery, provided that the voltage/amps/watts/etc (I am not an electrician!) match?

Thanks in advance for any general advice.

Rich

Answer (score 1):

If the voltage, amperage and wattage is the same, then yes, the battery most likely will be compatible. (capacity (A<sub>h</sub>) may vary).

The number of AmpHours (A<sub>h</sub>) will indicate how long the battery will last with a full charge. (1000 A<sub>h</sub> will last roughly twice as long as 500A<sub>h</sub>.)

Do take note of the fact that some manufacturers build in chips into the batteries, causing the laptop to only accept batteries manufactured/approved by the laptop's manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always, the 12 cell version has two sets of 6-cell "packs"; so the computer sees it as having a battery that's twice as big (instead of having twice as many).